# SQL CAST and different column types

Tags: sql, db2

Can't get my head around this. I need to run either `COALESCE` or `CASE` function in a simple IBM DB2 table. My initial approach was:

```
select a.number, a.text, case when a.text <> '' then a.text else a.number end
from MyTable a
```

`a.number` is `DECIMAL` and `a.text` is `CHARACTER`

If `a.text` is filled, I want to select this, otherwise `a.number`. The query above gives me a totally blank 3rd column. However simple logic test gives me expected values as answers:

```
select a.number, a.text, case when a.text <> '' then 1 else 2 end from MyTable a
```

The best I have been able to accomplish is:

```
select a.number, a.text, case when cast(a.number as VARCHAR(20)) <> 0  then
cast(a.number as VARCHAR(20)) else a.text end from MyTable
```

This provides both numeric values and if not available, also text, but in reality, I'm looking for the opposite way.

Am I struggling to use `CAST` function properly?

Comment: What’s the result of `case when a.text <> '' then hex(a.text) else a.number end` for such a “strange” row? Do you have Oracle compatibility mode turned on for your database?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a DBA, so not sure on Oracle compatibility. I do know it's DB2 running beneath and that's about it. As for your suggestion - unfortunately **a.text** is still blank. It's a step forward from my first option though which gave me blanks all around - this blanks out if **a.text** is filled, but does show **a.number** (in case **a.text** is not filled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't return two data types from a single column. So it has to be all VARCHAR or Numeric;

Below should fix your problem;

```
 select a.number, a.text, case when a.text <> '' then a.text else  cast(a.number as VARCHAR(20)) end from MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great! Looks like I had some excess code.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer soon, but I have a bit of trouble implementing this.
edit: never mind - i started losing **a.text** again as I was running the query in tandem with another column (linking them over **UNION ALL**) but after running CAST VARCHAR(20) on the other column too, it looks fine.

Comment: What's the result of the following query as is? `select a.number, a.text, case when a.text <> '' then a.text else char(a.number) end from table(values (dec(1), ''), (dec(1), '*'), (dec(1), cast(null as varchar(1)))) a (number, text)`

Comment: I'm getting an error message, I think the () are a bit of out place? Also, shouldn't it end with **as** (number, text) ?

Comment: This should work on Db2 for LUW. What’s your Db2 version and platform?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be on the safe side trim `text` and check its length with `coalesce()`.
If it is not `> 0` then cast `number` to `varchar(20)`:

```
select 
  a.number, a.text, 
  case 
    when coalesce(length(trim(a.text)), 0) > 0 then trim(a.text) 
    else cast(a.number as varchar(20))
  end 
from MyTable a
```